# How to insert the target terms of a glossary in all target segments of a sdlxliff file?

Tags: glossary

I have SDL Trados 2021.  I sometimes need to deliver the big projects from my regular clients within a tight deadline.  Therefore, I seek the help of my accomplished translator friends to finish them as per deadline.  But a few friends of mine do not have Trados and as a result they can't use the glossary which may cause severe inconsistency issues.

I earlier used to get rid of this issue by making a MS Word file, opening it in the Wordfast Pro (Version 3) with Copy source on no match ticked under Edit > Preferences > Translation Memory) in the TXML editor.  In addition to it, I also needed to tick the option number 2 or 3 in the Terminology:

Settings copy terms from source to target

Copy only source
Copy only target terms
Copy both source and target terms

But these options are not available in the current version of Wordfast Pro.  Instead, it has the following under Terminology:

Enable fuzzy term recognition
Enable term highlighting when typing terms
Ignore case for term highlighting

I now use Windows 11 and I can't open Wordfast Pro (Version 3) on it.  That is why, I looked to its current version but the earlier options are not available in it.  I could easily enter the glossary terms earlier as the English words in the target segments got replaced with the glossary terms when I clicked on each and every segment.

Can this be done with Trados or any other software?  Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

Rajan Chopra

I used the latest Wordfast Pro but the options are changed.